# NP algorithm for an optimization problem

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, optimization

Consider the following optimization problem

> **INSTANCE**: vectors $\vec{a}, \vec{b}, \vec{c}$, matrices $A, B$, threshold $\theta$.
>
> **PROBLEM**:
>
> Let $f={\displaystyle \max_{\vec{x}, \vec{y}}} (\vec{x}+\vec{c}) \cdot \vec{y}$
>
> subject to $A\vec{x}\leq \vec{a}$ and $B\vec{y}\leq \vec{b}$
>
> **Is $f \le \theta$** ?

This problem is in co-NP (provide a witness that $f > \theta$).

> Is this problem in NP ?

Comment: Can lagranges multiplier method be used to obtain the maximum value? (Just a random thought)

Comment: what does $\vec{x}\leq\vec{a}$ mean for vectors $\vec{x}$ and $\vec{a}$?

Comment: it's a componentwise comparison: shorthand for a set of inequalities.